# Search multiple query / paths in MongoDB Atlas Search

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I'm trying to create an api which will return search results which match more than one parameter.  I can query one parameter fine at the moment.

Here is an example url

http://localhost:3000/api/search?term=javascript&impact=sdg1

I want the results to include both term=javascript AND impact=sdg1

```
import Cors from "cors";
import initMiddleware from "../../util/init-middleware";
import { connectToDatabase } from "../../util/mongodb";

const cors = initMiddleware(
  Cors({
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"],
  })
);

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  await cors(req, res);

  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();

 const data = await db
    .collection("jobs")
    .aggregate([
      {
        $search: {
          search: [
            {
              query: req.query.term,
              path: ["title", "role"],
            },
            {
              query: req.query.impact,
              path: ["impact"],
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ])
    .sort({ date: -1 })
    .toArray();


  res.json(data);
}
```

Is this possible and can anyone suggest the right sort of query to write?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The way to accomplish this is with the `compound` operator. Here are the [docs](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/compound/) and here is how it would look in your code:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  await cors(req, res);

  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();

 const data = await db
    .collection("jobs")
    .aggregate([
      {
        $search: {
          "compound": {
              "must": [{
                  "text": {
                      "query": req.query.term,
                      "path": ["title", "role"],
                    }
                  }],
               "filter":[{
                    "text": {
                      "query": req.query.impact,
                      "path": ["impact"],
                    }
                }]
           }
        },
      },
    ])
    .sort({ date: -1 })
    .toArray();


  res.json(data);
}
```

Comment: dude. i tested it. And this does not work give the intended result. Must operator ignores the first `"text":{"query": req.query.term, path": ["title", "role"]}` and matches only with last `"text":{"query": req.query.impact,"path": ["impact"],}`

Comment: Take a look now